# does users have to be loggin-in to click like button on my website?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I am selling bags and I intend to have a "like" button for each bags's page. Is all "like" buttons in my product pages linked to my main facebook page, or can it be programmed to link to individual products and churns out comments and discussions on the particular product only?

Secondly, do users have to be logged-in to click on the like button?

Hope my question is not confusing, the way i phrase it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes user has to be logged in to FB to like any of ur products ..
but FB takes care of the logging part if the user is logged out, don't worry ..

u can map the like button to various pages by changing the url field in the like iframe ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

However, I saw the "recent Activities" and "Recommendations" plug-in. Does that mean that if users like a particular Product X, it will be reflected on the "Recommendations" plug-in and start a discussion on it?

Is it a must to place the "Recent Activities" and "Recommendations" plug-in in my own website or can I just leave it in facebook, make users click on "like" on my website then discuss on it on facebook itself?

Comment: Facebook puts no compulsion for putting like and Recent activities together .. they can be used as mutually exclusive entities ..

Comment: hi mahima, i mean if i wish to use both the recent activities and recommendations, is it a must to place it on my website for it to work or i can just have users click "like" on my website and reflect it on recommendations and recent actitivies over at facebook.

Comment: again.. they work mutually exclusive.. u can have just the like and the like feed shall be generated on the user's profile ..              in case the like iframe is for your fanpage on fb the count of its user likes shall increase